# How to enforce that a parameter is of the same static concrete type as the object?

Tags: dart, oop, covariance

I have a Flutter app connected to a Firestore database. I have a hierarchy of objects, let's say for example with abstract base class `Vehicle`, with subclasses such as `Car`, `Truck`, etc. Objects of these types are stored in the database. Due to how Firestore works, it is better to make these classes immutable, i.e. to make them essentially represent a *snapshot* of the conceptual object instead of the mutable object itself.

When I want to update a `Vehicle` object in the database, I don't want users of `Vehicle` (i.e. other parts of my code) to have to specify the update as a dynamic map, e.g. `vehicle.update({"speed": 42, "color": "red"})`, because this disables static checking of field names and types. Instead, I thought that the best way would be to make the users create the new snapshot they want, e.g. `car.setInDB(updatedCar)`. Behind the scenes this just calls `.set()` on the corresponding document reference in Firestore. Since the implementation would be the same on all subclasses of `Vehicle`, one could think of adding the method to `Vehicle`:

```dart
abstract class Vehicle {
  Future<void> setInDB(Vehicle updated) 
      => database.set(this.dbLocation, updated)
}
```

However, users of this method shouldn't be setting a vehicle of some concrete type with a vehicle of some other concrete type. I.e., a truck can only be updated with another truck snapshot, not a car snaphot. This is already enforced at runtime through Firestore rules, but I'd rather have this checked statically.

These options occur to me:

1. Use the `covariant` keyword and make subclasses override the `setInDB` method with the corresponding type.

   ```dart
   abstract class Vehicle {
     Future<void> setInDB(covariant Vehicle updated) 
         => database.set(this.dbLocation, updated)
   }
   ```

   ```dart
   class Car extends Vehicle {
     @override
     Future<void> setInDB(Car updated) 
         => super.setInDB(updated)
   }
   ```

   The problem with this is I might forget to override the method if I add a new subclass. Also, users could do `vehicle.setInDB(otherVehicle)`, where `vehicle` has static type `Vehicle`, and the correctness of `otherVehicle` would be checked at runtime again.
2. Only add the `setInDB` method to concrete subclasses of `Vehicle`, with the correct type:

   ```dart
   abstract class Vehicle {
   }
   ```

   ```dart
   class Car extends Vehicle {
     Future<void> setInDB(Car updated) 
         => database.set(this.dbLocation, updated)
   }
   ```

   ```dart
   class Truck extends Vehicle {
     Future<void> setInDB(Truck updated) 
         => database.set(this.dbLocation, updated)
   }
   ```

   Etc. The problem with this approach is the code duplication, since the implementation is the same everywhere.

Are there other options?

Comment: "The problem with this approach is the code duplication, since the implementation is the same everywhere.", maybe can just create a private method like `_save()` in the superclass to avoid the code duplication, (the duplication would be merely a function call). I don't know any way to refer a subclass type in the static analysis, only in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Dart 2.19 adds analyzer support for a `@mustBeOverridden` annotation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#tools-1) that you can add to a base class method. The analyzer then will emit a warning if a derived class neglects to override it. (However, as of writing, a new version of [`package:meta`](https://pub.dev/packages/meta) has not been published yet to add that annotation, but presumably it will be published soon.) For more details, see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30175.
- Borrow the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) from C++ and apply it to Dart generics by making your derived classes extend (or mixin) a generic base class that is parameterized on the derived class.  For example, I think that you could do:

  ```dart
  abstract class Vehicle<DerivedVehicle extends Vehicle<DerivedVehicle>> {
    Future<void> setInDB(DerivedVehicle updated)
        => database.set(this.dbLocation, updated)
  }

  class Car extends Vehicle<Car> {
  }

  class Truck extends Vehicle<Truck> {
  }
  ```

  and now `Car().setInDB()` should require a `Car` argument, and `Truck().setInDB()` should expect a `Truck`.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Wouldn't `Vehicle<DerivedVehicle extends Vehicle>` be enough for the CRTP?

Comment: @Anakhand `Vehicle<DerivedVehicle extends Vehicle>` apparently isn't allowed ("Type parameter bound types must be instantiated.").  You could just use `class Vehicle<DerivedVehicle>` if you want a simpler declaration that doesn't restrict `DerivedVehicle`.